# Excel Validation list created from a large array

Tags: vba, excel

**The objective**
I have to create a dropdown list for the user to scroll through and select an item. The items are the company's contracts, as stored in our directories. There are thousands of them.

**The attempts**
My first attempt was to use a sub which goes through our directory and writes the name of each contract's folder in `column` L on `sheet` f_param. I then used the following code to create the validation list:

```
With f_param.Range("cell_titreprojet").Validation
    .delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:="=Paramètres!$L$3:$l$1406"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
```

It worked very well, but I felt like storing the names in an `array`, and then directly using the `array`'s `values` to populate the list would be better.

I used this post as a reference: [Excel Validation Drop Down list using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18885513/excel-validation-drop-down-list-using-vba)

I managed to create the validation list from a directory containing 10 items without problem using this code:

```
Sub Example2()
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objSubFolder As Object
Dim i As Integer
Dim liste() As String


'Create an instance of the FileSystemObject
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'Get the folder object
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("O:")
i = 0
'loops through each file in the directory and stores their path
For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.subfolders
    If IsNumeric(Left(objSubFolder.Name, 1)) Then
        'print folder path
        ReDim Preserve liste(i)
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next objSubFolder


With Feuil2.Range("A1").Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
        Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=Join(liste, ",")
End With
End Sub
```

**The issue**

When I change from directory O: (the tested one, 10 folders) to H: (which is the one I want), the `array` is filled correctly (I printed the 1403 folder names in a `column` to check), but I recieved an `error` during the list's creation (using the same code posted previously, that worked with a smaller array). Does anyone have an idea why?

EDIT: The error is 1004 (roughly translated from French) : Error defined by application or object.

Comment: If nobody can answer, feel free to help me do it the first way (storing the names in a hidden column and using this to populate the list). I just need to understand how to refer to named cells (Instead of populating from L3 to L X I would like to populate from a named cell to end of list.)

Comment: What error message are you getting and from which line?

Comment: The error is 1004 (roughly translated from French) : Error defined by application or object. I added it to the question. it happens at `.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _ Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=Join(liste, ",")`

Comment: At first I thought it was because a list cannot be that long, but since I created it successfully when it came from excel sheet values (the ones I put in column L) , that would not be the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This page](http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal08.html#itemlimit) says that there are different limits depending on how the list is built.

> There are limits to the number of items that will show in a data validation drop down list: The list can show up to 32,767 items from a list on the worksheet. If you type the items into the data validation dialog box (a delimited list), the limit is 256 characters, including the separators.
>   If you need more items than that, you could create a dependent drop down list, broken down by category.

Comment: Does filling it using an array fall into the "typing in the data validation box" category?? That doesn't seem likely. Either way, creating a dependant drop down list the way they show it really doesn't fit my needs as the number of contracts (length of list) varies. I could spawn the list from values from a sheet using VBA - if i knew how to reference a varying range from this type of command: `Formula1:="=Feuil2!$A$3:$A$10"`
Instead of going from `A3` to `A10` I could reference a named cell, and another named cell. Do you know how?

Comment: I thought that you were able to get it working using "column L on sheet f_param" or was there a problem with that?

Comment: Filling it using an array creates a text list in the same way as typing the data so I suspect the limit is around the size of the text list. Using a range on a worksheet, the list simply shows the address of the range being used.

Comment: You're probably right. I ended up dropping the idea and using Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker) for them to pick it from there. It was simpler and also better because of dropdown list of 1000+ items is pretty bad in the first place.