# Why does scripting dictionary corrupt data

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

I have data set which I parse with code to produce Data validation drop down list. This code works with one choice but taking another choice breaks the excel when saving and opening again. I'm thinking there might be some characters that dont work with scripting.dictionary.

AStr is the selected data which has duplicates. I use scripting.dictionary to remove duplicates. "AStr" at this point looks like ",material 1, material 1, food cart, nuts&bolts".

```
If IsEmpty(AStr) = False Then

If AStr <> "," Then
        AStr = Right(AStr, Len(AStr) - 1)
        AStr_split = Split(AStr, ",")
        Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary
        Dim part As Variant
            For Each part In AStr_split
                    dict(part) = 1 'doesn't matter which value we're putting in here
        Next
        AStr_final = Join(dict.keys, ",")
     
        With Worksheets("Lead time").Range("C" & Current_row).Validation
                .Delete
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
                xlBetween, Formula1:=AStr_final
                .IgnoreBlank = True
                .InCellDropdown = True
                .InputTitle = ""
                .ErrorTitle = ""
                .InputMessage = ""
                .ErrorMessage = ""
                .ShowInput = True
                .ShowError = True
        End With
End If
End If
```

Code works but saving the workbook and opening it again after running that script results in
*"We found problem with some content in #filename# Do you want us to recover as much as we can"* Excel has repaired script in "Private Sub Worksheet_Change". But the error occurs even if Worksheet_change is never triggered as I tried running the problem script alone.

EDIT:
Tim Williams is probably right. I think this might do with number of characters in the string (Astr_final) that is used in data validation. In my case the working choice string was ~200 characters and the file corruption string was around 700.

Now I just need to figure out how to make my comma delimited string into a named list which I reference in data validation Formula1

Comment: Private Sub Worksheet_Change probably is triggered.

Comment: Could we also see the beginning and the end of your procedure since there may be the part that is causing this to happen? The dictionary has probably nothing to do with it. You can always test `Debug.Print AStr_final` if necessary.

Comment: There is a limit to the length of the list you can use for validation (256 chars)  If your list is long then you could put it on a worksheet and link the validation to that range.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30669281/excel-validation-list-created-from-a-large-array