# Creating ListBox

Tags: excel, ms-access, listbox, vba

I'm trying to create an Excel report from Access using VBA. So every time a user clicks on a button in an Access form an Excel file should be generated. I need to have ListBox in the file. I'm declaring ListBox adding items but have problem with assigning it to specific cell:

```
Dim lst As ListBox
With lst
.AddItem "1"
.AddItem "2"
End With
```

Now I want to display listbox in Cells(7, 1).

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution is to utilize data validation to create a drop-down in the cell directly. This way you also avoid using potentially deprecating components.

In your case, this could be running this code:

```
Dim list(1) As String
list(0) = "1"
list(1) = "2"

With Cells(1, 7).Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
        Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=Join(list, ",")
End With
```

Adding the validation using Join was inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18885513/excel-validation-drop-down-list-using-vba).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried, but getting runtime error 1004.

Comment: When? How are you using the code? It works perfectly fine here.

Comment: I'm using it under With xlapp

Comment: on button click event function I'm creating excel file using 'code' Set xlapp = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 'create an excel application object
With xlapp
.Workbooks.Add 'add new workbook in the excel
.ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Text", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False

Comment: I'm pretty sure your problem is beyond the scope of the question and answer. Try to execute the code above in an empty method in a new workbook and see if it causes any trouble.

Comment: No it does not, if I create excel file and run the code. However, I'm trying to generate one from access as I mentioned above, so I can't skip creating excel and write just that code in button click event function.

Comment: Of course not. My point is that if you have a new problem that has nothing to do with your question and my answer, you should probably add a description of the new problem in your main question or create a new question. This is supposed to be an answer to what you ask - not a longer consultancy session in which I solve your other problems.